# Is there a way to input test and train data separately without splitting it to a classifier algorithm?

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

I'm trying to create a Naive Bayes Classifier in Python. For finding the accuracy of the classifier, I have train and test data explicitly available, and I want to train my model using train.csv and then test it on test.csv.

Is there a function except scikit test_train_split which can help me doing that?

Comment: why do you need a function when your train data and test data are already separated (train.csv and test.csv). Please clarify what is that additional thing you are looking for which is not supported by `test_train_split`

Comment: Basically, what I'm looking for is that train_test_split is used for splitting a particular dataset into train and test datasets. But I already have them splitted, all I need to know is how to use either of them as an input to my classifier algorithm.

Comment: As @mujjiga mentioned, the `test_train_split()` would not be need. If it is a part of an existing code, then it may bypassed. Briefly, you would do the following:

Answer (score 0):

Following from comment above:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Create an instance
nv_clf = GaussianNB()

# Fit on training set
nv_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Pedict on X_test
y_pred = nv_clif.predict(X_test)

# Calcuate error/accuracy on y_test
nv_mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred) 
# or
nv_rmse = np.sqrt(nv_mse) # root mean squared error
```

Comment: I don't want to split my test data into validation datasets...I want to use it as it is.